# SQLAlchemy inheritance not working

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy. I have used my own abstract base class and inheritance. When I try to use my models in the python shell I get the following error:

```
>>> from schedule.models import Task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/teelf/projects/schedule/server/schedule/models.py", line 14, in <module>
    class User(Base):
  File "/home/teelf/projects/schedule/server/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 536, in __init__
    DeclarativeMeta.__init__(self, name, bases, d)
  File "/home/teelf/projects/schedule/server/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 55, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "/home/teelf/projects/schedule/server/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 254, in _as_declarative
    **table_kw)
  File "/home/teelf/projects/schedule/server/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 393, in __new__
    "existing Table object." % key)
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'user' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns
 on an existing Table object.
```

How do I fix this?

**Code:**

**manage.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask.ext.script import Manager

from server import create_app
from database import db


app = create_app("config")

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command("db", MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

**__init__.py**:

```
from flask import Flask

from flask.ext.login import LoginManager

from database import db
from api import api
from server.schedule.controllers import mod_schedule


def create_app(config):
    # initialize Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # load configuration file
    app.config.from_object(config)

    # initialize database
    db.init_app(app)

    api.init_app(app)

    # initialize flask-login
    login_manager = LoginManager(app)

    # register blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(mod_schedule)

    return app
```

**database.py**:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**models.py**:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

from database import db


class Base(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = db.Column(UUID, primary_key=True)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    username = db.Column(db.String)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String)
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.username = username

    def is_active(self):
        """ All users are active """
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self.authenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        """ Anonymous users are not supported"""
        return False
```

**controllers.py**:

```
from flask import Blueprint

from flask.ext.restful import reqparse, Resource

from api import api
from server.schedule.models import User


mod_schedule = Blueprint("schedule",  __name__, url_prefix="/schedule")


class Task(Resource):
    def put(self):
        pass

    def get(self):
        pass

    def delete(self):
        pass


api.add_resource(Task, "/tasks/<int:id>", endpoint="task")
```

Comment: Two things that might be helpful (although I haven't had the chance to test them): a) when initializing `SQLAlchemy()` use your Flask app (e.g. `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`; b) `users` is a [reserved key word in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), so maybe `__tablename__ = "users"` might end up in some conflict.

Comment: @cuducos a) I have `db.init_app(app)` in `__init__.py`. b) the tablename in my code is `user` not `users`.

Comment: @teelf How are you managing migrations/creation of the tables? Is it possible to share your `__init__.py` or more bits of your application?

Comment: @cuducos I forgot manage.py, I use alembic for migration/table creation. Sorry about all the code.

Comment: @teelf, not good news: I replicated all your code locally and ran the `import` with no errors: `In [1]: from server.schedule.models import Task \n In [2]:` Probably the error is elsewhere…

Comment: Is there more code in `models.py` that you haven't posted?

Answer (score 63):

Try adding

```
 __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
```

to your User class right under `__tablename__=`

cheers

Comment: Where did you learn this, and can you share in the SQLalchemy docs where is case is spoken about more? (You answer is just what I needed)

Comment: While this is useful in some cases, in general this should not be needed and is a sign that the table definitions are created multiple times – usually by accident. Throwing it as a generic "just copy and paste this to your code" solution is misleading and just hides the real errors.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html?highlight=__table_args__) to sqlalchemy docs, where \_\_table_args\_\_ dict is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you don't already have data in your pre-existing database, is to drop it, recreate it without the tables. Then interactively run your "models.py" script (you would need to add a little code at the bottom to allow this), then in the interactive Python console do "db.create_all()" and it should create the tables based on your classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution here:
https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/672#issuecomment-478195961

> So, basically we hit the union of two problems:
>
> 1. Having left over `.pyc` files on the disk.
> 2. Git Ignoring empty directories full of files in `.gitignore`
>
> Deleting the directories and cleaning the `.pyc` files solved the problem.