# Flask SqlAlchemy Table Already Define Error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a flask app which at the moment is small and has one table model created using flask-sqlalchemy.

The app currently imports the table from two separate files while the app is running, and seems to be ok.

The problem is when try to directly run the file I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'User' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.

The model code is:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Presumably, the model is already created when `from app import db` is executed. So when line `class User(db.Model):` is called the error is raised.

I can include `__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}` in the table model which does prevent the error. However, I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812250/sqlalchemy-inheritance-not-working) that this is could be hiding errors.

It is ok to include this line or is there likely to be something wrong with my code?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908767/table-roles-users-is-already-defined-for-this-metadata-instance ?